# I have a question in designing crystal oscillator

Tags: oscillator, crystal

I want to design a crystal oscillator (pierce) but I'm having trouble.
Proposed oscillation frequency is around 39 MHz and I used crystal 
L~4mH C~4.1fF R~10ohm; Co~2pF

C1,C2=20pF (shunt cap for drain to GND & gate to GND)

Feedback resistor ~ 1 Mohm;
Vdd~1.5V
Transistor gm~80u

However, my oscillator input/output settles to same voltage, and does not oscillate.

When I change crystal cap to 200 fF then it starts oscillation.

- Can crystal motional cap affect to oscillation?
- What is the cause for non oscillating?

[image: pierce oscillator]
This is the schematic of my design.

Comment: what does "~" mean here? do you mean "approximately", or did you actually mean "="?

Comment: Shall we provide solutions to school assignments?

Comment: @AliChen Shall we provide solutions to job assignments?

Comment: @pipe, that's one good question. If a person starts with "I want to design" and does not know about negative impedance concept in Pierce Oscillator, I think my answer is NO.

Comment: Show your circuit diagram.

Comment: @MarcusMüller it means approximately (because i leave out decimal point. real value i designed was like 4.008mH, 4.1039fF)

Comment: @Andyaka I attached my circuit design :)

Comment: @AliChen I'm sorry for my question's tone... But it is neither my school assignment, nor job assignment. I am studying about oscillator now by myself, and I read the book and studied concept of negative impedance. However, during design process, application of the concept was difficult. Thus, I wanted to get other's opinion how to start the design well.

Comment: Sure, I do understand your curioucity. That's why you are using a professional-grade  transistor-level ASIC design tool Virtuoso from Cadence, with SPICE license? Then you have selected probably the worst design topic for your self-learning.

Answer (score 2):

The only reason for lack of oscillation is insufficient gain to cover attenuation loss in parallel resonant circuit with 180 phase inversion in CLC resonator and 180 deg inverting amplifier.

All circuit elements shape the Q of the resonator ( Typ ~10k) especially the motional capacitance which is very small with a very large inductance.

- Although at these frequencies often Colpitts series mode is preferred design due to low impedance in parallel mode. then ESR is a critical parameter for loop gain
- If in doubt, just buy the OSC chip with Xtal
- (cheap < $1 in volume)  < 7mA@1.8V
- e.g. http://www.taitien.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/XO-0072-OX-Type.pdf

I *could* analyze your Pierce design but I would bet money that Xtal impedance in resonant mode is lower than driver impedance, thus high insertion loss and insufficient gain in transistor.

Pierce Osc.

[image]
[image]

Hartley Osc.
[image]

For more details ref> http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?baseLiteratureNumber=snaa065&fileType=pdf

Comment: A pierce oscillator uses series resonance not parallel as far as I know.